# RabbitMQ .NET client CreateConnection is sometimes slow after the first call, while already listening to messages

Tags: c#, .net, rabbitmq

I'm using the RabbitMQ.Client 5.1.0 NuGet package in a .NET Core 2.1 application. It opens multiple connections to the same RabbitMQ server to listen to queue messages. I find that the first call to `ConnectionFactory.CreateConnection()` is always fast (100 ms or so), but subsequent calls, made while already listening, can sometimes take 3-10 seconds.

Some simple code to reproduce the problem:

```
        for (var i = 1; i <= 10; ++i)
        {
            var factory = new ConnectionFactory
            {
                HostName = hostName,
                UserName = userName,
                Password = password
            };

            var stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
            var connection = factory.CreateConnection();
            Console.WriteLine($"[{i}] CreateConnection took {stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds:N0} ms");

            var channel = connection.CreateModel();
            channel.BasicQos(0, 200, false);

            var consumer = new EventingBasicConsumer(channel);

            channel.BasicConsume(queueName, false, consumer);
        }
```

(The real application starts each connection on separate thread, but that doesn't seem to make a difference.)

Typical output:

```
[1] CreateConnection took 109 ms
[2] CreateConnection took 38 ms
[3] CreateConnection took 61 ms
[4] CreateConnection took 362 ms
[5] CreateConnection took 390 ms
[6] CreateConnection took 1,261 ms
[7] CreateConnection took 3,043 ms
[8] CreateConnection took 1,047 ms
[9] CreateConnection took 381 ms
[10] CreateConnection took 376 ms
```

Am I doing something wrong or does this look like an issue with the RabbitMQ client library?

Answer (score 0):

Please note that creating a connection is not free and can be affected by load on your servers as well as the network. A TCP socket must be established and AMQP handshake completed. I suggest doing a packet capture to confirm the creation times and correlate them with TCP connection setup.

It may not matter, but all the examples I see of the `Stopwatch` class call the `Stop` method before reading properties from the current instance.

Comment: Well sure it can be affected by load, but other connections (to the same server) don't take seconds to establish. Could you elaborate on what to look for in the packet capture? I don't quite understand what you mean by "confirm the creation times and correlate them with TCP connection setup"

Comment: Other connections are to other services and are for different protocols, however. You can't really compare apples to oranges here. The packet capture will show a duration between packets. You can see how long the initial TCP handshake takes, then the flow of packets for the AMQP handshake. It should illustrate where the time is being taken up. If you see time between the initial handshake and when the first AMQP handshake packet is sent from the client, then maybe there's something to investigate in the client code. Most likely, however, it is specific to your environment.

Comment: I took the time to test this against a local RabbitMQ 3.7.13 node and one running on my home server. In both cases, connections always took around 70ms to be established. You can find the code and results [here](https://github.com/lukebakken/rabbitmq-tutorials/tree/dotnet-connection-time-55264978/dotnet/ConnectionTimeTest).

Comment: Actually, I had a bug in my code. With it fixed, you can see that the initial connection takes about 70 ms then subsequent ones take far less time. This is of course specific to my environment where RabbitMQ is running with zero load, and hardly any load on my network.

Comment: May I ask what bug did you have? I'm in the very same trouble...